# SQLServer SSIS Error connecting to AS400

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ibm-midrange

I made a data source with this propierties:

1. Provider "Native OLE DB\IBM DB" for i5/OS IBMDA400 OLE DB Provider",
2. User id and the password are filled.
3. Persist Security is true.
4. Catalog library list is filled.

I made the connection manager based on the data source, I made a OLE DB Source with this Connection manager, It show me the list of the tables name, I choose the table I need But when I click OK SSIS returns an error that says:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "IBMDA400 Session"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "CWBZZ5010 Error de comunicaciones con el sistema ###.#.##.# ".

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: Opening a rowset for ""XXXXXX".XXXX" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC02020E8 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

I hope you understand me, I have a pretty poor english. Ty

Comment: Make sure your Package collection property is set appropriately

Comment: It should be listed in your connection manager all propertier

Comment: Do you mean default collection? Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with ADO NET manager Connection and It works. Ty all

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a timeout connection problem.

[Check this IBM technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1016313)